# Fetch type use case for @ManyToOne and @LazyToOne

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

If `FetchType.LAZY` attribute is set for `@ManyToOne` annotation -

```
//use case 1
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

does `@LazyToOne` annotation need to be used along with `@ManyToOne`? -

```
//use case 2
@ManyToOne
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
```

Or Use case 1 and 2 are equivalent to each other?

Answer (score 2):

In case of Many-to-One mapping, yes these 2 cases would be equivalent

as  in case of one-to-many, empty collection proxy is created initially and populated on demand, so the association can be lazy.

But that would not be the case for One-To-One mapping.
You would need to use,

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

As the equivalent version

The reason for this is that mapped entity MUST know whether association property should contain a proxy object or NULL and it can't determine that by looking at its base table's columns due to one-to-one normally being mapped via shared PK, so it has to be eagerly fetched anyway making proxy pointless

Refer [Here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one) for more details on how lazy loading works for One-to-one and many-to-one mapping.